# ¿Como conectar un sensor RFID-RC522 de arduino a wpf?

Tags: c#, c, wpf, arduino

Estoy utilizando un sensor de arduino que va dirigido a un softwarecon bases de datos, utilizaria las tarjetas para agregar identificadores y que los clientes puedan acceder solo con mostrar su tarjeta, solo que tengo algunos problemas leyendo el serialport desde wpf.

Esto es un software de WPF con una base de datos en SQLServer 2014 y un sensor RFID de arduino

```
        puertoArduino = new SerialPort();
        puertoArduino.PortName = "COM7";
        puertoArduino.BaudRate = 9600;
        puertoArduino.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        puertoArduino.DataBits = 8;
        puertoArduino.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        puertoArduino.DataReceived += PuertoArduino_DataReceived;
        puertoArduino.Open();
```

También utilizo estos dos métodos:

```
private void PuertoArduino_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) { 

in_data = puertoArduino.ReadLine();
Dispatcher.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event)); 

} 

private void displaydata_event(object sender, EventArgs e) {

 txtCodigo.Text = in_data; 

}
```

Comment: Tambien utilizo estos dos metodos:
      private void PuertoArduino_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            in_data = puertoArduino.ReadLine();

            Dispatcher.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event));
        }

        private void displaydata_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtCodigo.Text = in_data;
        }

Comment: cual seria el problema de leer el serial port desde wpf ? porque mencionas tienes un problema, luego muestras el codigo pero nunca explicas cual es el problema?

Comment: Estaba un poco inestable por que el puerto se abria, pero no se cerraba y el programa me mostraba error, agregue un par de cosas. Ya puse el metodo que me funciono por si alguien tenia el mismo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifique mi metodo, y me funciono.

```
if (puertoArduino.IsOpen)
        {
            in_data = puertoArduino.ReadLine();
            if (in_data == "10674F39\r")
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    txtCodigo.Text = "3";
                });
                puertoArduino.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            puertoArduino.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaria en estos casos no te centres en `wpf`, sino utiliza una implementacion existente que ayude a testear si verdaderamente recibes datos desde el puerto serie

Algo como ser:

[GUI based Serial Communication Program using C#](https://www.xanthium.in/building-opensource-gui-based-serial-port-communication-program-dot-net-framework-and-arduino)

Esta implementacion no esta en wpf, pero usa `.net` con lo cual al pasarlo a wpf sera practicamente la misma implementacion ya que usa

```
System.IO.Ports
```

y la clase `SerialPort` que es lo mismo que deberias utilizar para cualquier tipo de proyecto que desarrolles sobre `.net`

Del articulo puedes descargar el .exe y probar que puerto esta recibiendo los datos ya que los cambias desde la interfaz

Comment: Gracias Leandro, ya encontre la solucion.
La posteo en breve.